# PHP Laravel : Autocomplete Search 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm building a laravel application where I have to use autocomplete search in my application.

My Route:

```
Route::get('/autocomplete',[
        'uses'=>'CourseController@autocomplete',
        'as'=>'autocomplete'
        ]);
```

My Controller:

```
 public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {

        $item = $request->input(['searchname']);
        $results=array();
        $queries = DB::table('courses')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')  
        ->take(5)->get();

        foreach ($queries as $data) {
          $results[]=['id'=>$data->id,'value'=>$data->name];
        }
    return Response::json($results);
    }
```

My View Page:

```
 {{ Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@autocomplete'], 'method' => 'GET']) }}
    {{ Form::text('searchname', '', ['id' =>  'searchname', 'placeholder' =>  'Enter name'])}}
    {{ Form::submit('Search', array('class' => 'button expand')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}


    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#searchname').autocomplete({
            source:  "/autocomplete" ,
            minlength:1,
            autofocus:true,
            select:function(event,ui){
              $("searchname").val(ui.item.value);
            }
      });
      });
    </script>
```

So when I search for a item instead of getting item name i'm getting following Error in my console:

```
GET http://localhost/autocomplete?term=tree 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyone who can help me to find the solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` for your autocomplete is the problem. You are passing a path relative to your server document root, rather than a route within your site.
Also, you don't need the form, since the search is done asynchronously.

You can try this

```
<input type="text" id="searchname" placeholder="Enter name"/>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#searchname').autocomplete({
        source: "{{ route('autocomplete') }}" ,
        minlength:1,
        autofocus:true,
        select:function(event,ui){
          $("searchname").val(ui.item.value);
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

---

EDIT: I'm assuming the root of your site is at `http://localhost/your-site` and not just `localhost`.
Also, in your Routes you are using `CourseController` then in the form you write `UserController`. Since you are naming the route anyway it would be good to use the `route`helper to generate the correct URL.

---

Finally, in your controller you should get the input of name "term", not "searchname".

```
$term = $request->term;
```